# react-bootstrap and DropDown with multiple Columns from REST service

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap to display a form in a react component.
I have a DropDown defined like that:

```
                        <Dropdown>
                            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="secondary">
                                Infos auswählen
                            </Dropdown.Toggle>
                            <Dropdown.Menu variant="dark">
                                <Dropdown.Item><tr><td>ID 1</td><td>Keyname 1</td></tr></Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item><tr><td>ID 2jfskdljlksjflksfjlksfdl</td><td>Info 2</td></tr></Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item><tr><td>ID 3</td><td>Keyname 3</td></tr></Dropdown.Item>
                            </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
```

The Dropdown should display the Information in 2 Colums ("ID" and "additional Info"). And the Dropdown Items should be fetch from an REST service using axios.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - I don't know if it's a best solution:

- Use Table component in your Dropdown.Menu
- Dump Dropdown.Items (maybe you can still use them, when you wrap every tr with them, but you need to at least adjust the styles)
- Iterate over / map your backend data to tr/td and appropriate onClick event
- Set the value on click and hide the Dropdown.Menu

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-panka-uz6z0d

```
const additionalInfo = [
    { id: "ID 1", additionalInfo: "Keyname 1" },
    { id: "ID 2", additionalInfo: "Keyname 2" },
    { id: "ID 3", additionalInfo: "Keyname 3" }
  ];
  
const [selectedValue, selectValue] = useState(null);
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

return (
<Stack direction="horizontal" className="m-3 align-items-center" gap={3}>
  <Dropdown show={show} onToggle={(show) => setShow(show)}>
    <Dropdown.Toggle variant="secondary">Infos auswählen</Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu variant="dark">
      <Table hover borderless variant="dark" style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
        <tbody>
          {additionalInfo.map((data) => {
            return (
              <tr
                key={data.id}
                onClick={() => {
                  selectValue(data);
                  setShow(false);
                }}
              >
                <td>{data.id}</td>
                <td>{data.additionalInfo}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
  <span>{`Selected value is: ${selectedValue?.additionalInfo}`}</span>
</Stack>
);
```

As alternative, you could also use Grid to create table-like Dropdown.Items.